# float value to time(HH:MM) FORMAT

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
hr = int(input("Enter period of earth rotation : "))

ln = float(input("Enter value of longitude : "))

calc = (hr/360)*ln

print (calc)
```

INPUT:- `24,82.50`

I expect the output to be `5:30`, instead of `5.5`

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
hr = int(input("Enter period of earth rotation : "))

ln = float(input("Enter value of longitude : "))

calc = (hr/360)*ln
hours = int(calc)
minutes = (calc*60) % 60

print("%d:%02d" % (hours, minutes))
```

**Output**

```
Enter period of earth rotation : 24
Enter value of longitude : 82.50
5:30
```

Comment: it worked, can you please tell me what actually %02d specifies?

Comment: It specifies that you are printing upto 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got `calc`, the exact time in hours, and what you need is to convert the decimal to some number of minutes. I'd do this by storing hours and minutes separately:

```
hours = int(calc)
minutes = int((calc - hours) * 60)
print(f"{hours}:{minutes:02}")
```